# Как найти расстояние между точкой и дугой на сфере?

Tags: геометрия

Здравствуйте.
Допустим у меня есть 3 географические координаты заданные широтой и долготой, первые две из которых образуют дугу, а третья лежит за её пределами. Есть ли способ найти ближайшую точку на дуге к третьей точке и расстояние до неё?

Comment: способ безусловно есть. Если расстояние считать по дуге, то там будет такая же логика как и кратчайшее расстояние от точки до от отрезка. Нужно искать перпендикуляр. А можно просто сделать аккуратную проекцию. Ну или использовать тернарный поиск.

Comment: через две точки можно провести бесконечное количество дуг. не очень понятно, как они ее образуют. А через любые три можно провести окружность :)

Comment: Да, есть способ найти и так далее. Этот способ - изучить геометрию в объеме восьмого класса средней школы (или сейчас это уже девятый?).

Comment: @splash58, это не произвольная дуга, а сегмент окружности.

Comment: @Arhad хорошо, сформулируем так: через две точки можно провести бесконечное количество окружностей. Центры которых лежат на прямой, перпендикулярной и проходящей через центр отрезка, соединяющего точки

Comment: @splash58, у автора широта и долгота, то есть полярные координаты. А там, где известны полярные координаты, известен и центр сферы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вот вам наброски.

Для вычислений перейдите в декартову систему координат, вычислять в терминах широты и долготы ужасно неудобно.

Ближайшая (то есть нужная вам) точка лежит в плоскости, перпендикулярной дуге и проходящей через третью точку, не лежащую на этой дуге.

> [image: Точки]
>
> *A, B и C — данные точки, X — искомая. Упомянутая плоскость закрашена голубым.*
>
> *Перпендикуляр дуги окружности всегда «смотрит» от центра O этой окружности. Благодаря этому плоскость, перпендикулярная дуге, всегда проходит через этот центр.*

Чтобы найти эту плоскость, вам нужно найти два лежащих в ней вектора, а затем найти с помощью их векторного произведения нормаль (перпендикуляр) к этой плоскости. Пусть этими векторами будут:

- радиус-вектор третьей точки,
- нормаль к дуге. Её можно посчитать как векторное произведение радиус-векторов  точек *A* и *B*, лежащих на дуге.

> [image: Вектора]
>
> *R<sub>A</sub>, R<sub>B</sub> R<sub>C</sub> — радиус-вектора точек A, B и C соответственно, N — нормаль к дуге. К слову, N может смотреть и в другую сторону (это зависит от порядка множителей в векторном произведении), но в целом это не имеет значения.*

Стоит отметить, что мы не будем выражать уравнение плоскости. Нам необходима только её нормаль.

Теперь построим ещё одну плоскость, проходящую через дугу и центр, и найдём линию пересечения этих двух плоскостей (на первом рисунке это линия *OX*). Плоскости заведомо перпендикулярны (так как заведомо перпендикулярны лежащие в каждой из них *CX* и *AB*), поэтому направление прямой пересечения можно найти через векторное произведение их нормалей; в качестве же свободного члена уравнения этой прямой можно взять центр сферы *O*.

Теперь, отойдя от *O* вдоль *OX* на расстояние радиуса сферы, вы получите искомую точку. Точнее, две, так как вдоль *OX* можно идти в двух направлениях.

Осталось выяснить, какая из этих точек нам нужна. Если на дуге *AB* лежит только одна из них, то ответ очевиден. В случае же, когда на дуге лежат обе точки, придётся сравнивать расстояния и находить минимум.

Comment: Хотелось бы почитать комментарии минусующего.

Comment: Скорее всего минусанули за сложность формулировок. Сейчас постараюсь исправить ситуацию.

Comment: @Arhad: А, ну как бы да, если подробно расписывать, то будет длинно, а мне лень. А готовый код писать я не буду, понятно.

Comment: Выложил наполовину откорректированный текст. Просто большинство плохо воспринимают длинные простыни со сложноподчинёнными предложениями. Плюс пространственное мышление не у всех развито.

Comment: @VladD вы наверное не учили сферическую тригонометрию :)

Comment: @Barmaley: Если у вас есть решение изящнее, публикуйте!

Comment: @Arhad: Ох, ничего себе вы дополнили! Спасибо! Сделаю-ка я ответ общим.

Comment: @Arhad: Подкорректировал немного. Нам не нужно пересчитытват; в двумерную систему координат, просто этот кусок рассмотрения весь лежит в одной плоскости.

Comment: @VladD, редактирование закончил. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, нет ли каких несостыковок, ошибок и прочих шероховатостей.

Comment: @Arhad: По идее, нам вовсе не нужно уравнение плоскости («Как только мы выразили плоскость (через уравнение плоскости по точке и вектору нормали)»), мы работает с векторами, то есть нужна просто нормаль,

Comment: @VladD, исправил. Но примечание всё равно оставил, чтобы вопрос "а как мы эту плоскость будем использовать" снялся сразу, а не предложение спустя.

Comment: @Arhad: Ага, выглядит как надо, спасибо!

Comment: @Arhad: Надо бы ещё сказать в начале, что ближайшая точка есть основание перпендикуляра, но только если этот перпендикуляр попадает на дугу. Для «тупоугольного» случая ближайшей точкой будет один из концов дуги. (Для этого у нас перебор в конце.)

Comment: @Arhad: Подождите, у вас потерялся при редактировании ещё один случай, когда дуга короткая, и точки пересечения на неё не попадают. Для этого случая надо выбрать один из концов дуги. https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQwO1.png

Answer (score 1):

Это типичная задача из сферической тригонометрии - то есть когда точки/линии находятся на поверхности сферы, а не на плоскости.

Общий паттерн решения задач сферической тригонометрии следующий:

1. Переносите решение на планиметрию (то есть на плоскости)
2. Решаете ее с помощью обычных средств с применением теоремы синусов и косинусов
3. Далее возвращаетесь на сферу и заменяете плоские теоремы синусов и косинусов на их сферические аналоги: [сферическая теорема косинусов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2) и [сферическая теорема синусов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%84%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2)

То есть у вас есть отрезок и точка. Надо опустить на этот отрезок высоту и понять где высота пересекает отрезок - это и будет искомая точка. Задачка для школьника... Только надо помнить, что нельзя пользоваться некоторыми планиметрическими теоремами - например, на плоскости сумма углов треугольника всегда 180, а на сфере нет - там есть т.н. сферический избыток.

В общем как то так.